# The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is wrong with this SQL query?

```
SELECT id AS Expr 
FROM EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.Exceptions 
WHERE EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.Exceptions.exceptionID = EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.RoomView.exceptionID
```

When I try to execute the query I get this error message:

```
Msg  4104, Level  ##, State  1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.Exceptions.exceptionID" could not be bound.
Msg  4104, Level  ##, State  1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.RoomView.exceptionID" could not be bound.
```

RoomView is a view and Exceptions is a table.

Comment: what is EXTDATA??? Are you using linked server?

Comment: @timus2001 Yes I'm working on a linked server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.RoomView` view is not mentioned in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clause of the query. You cannot reference a view or a table in a `WHERE` clause expression like that: you need to add `EXISTS` or a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT id AS Expr 
FROM EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.Exceptions e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.RoomView v
    WHERE e.exceptionID = v.exceptionID
)
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT id AS Expr
FROM EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.Exceptions e
JOIN EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.RoomView v ON e.exceptionID = v.exceptionID
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you after join

```
SELECT id AS Expr 
FROM EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.Exceptions EX
     INNER JOIN EXTDATA.Monitoring.dbo.RoomView RW ON EX.exceptionID = RW.exceptionID
```